# insert into a join table mysqli oop

Tags: php

i have these tables in database:

```
country:    id    country
```

and i have segment table:

```
segments:  id   segment
```

and the third table named countrysegments have foreign key: country id related to country.id and segment_id related to country.id

```
countrysegments:     id   country_id    segment_id
```

in index.php i have this:

```
 <div class="col-md-12">
            <table id="tbl" class = "table table-bordered table-responsive  ">
            <thead>

                            <th class="text-center">country</th>

                            <th class="text-center">segments</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php

                require 'class.php';

                $conn = new db_class();
                $read = $conn->select();
                                    $test = $conn->read();

                 while($fetch = $read->fetch_array()){                      
                                  ?>
```

```
    </td><td><select name="" id="">
            <?php
            $reads = $conn->read();

            while($fetch = $reads->fetch_array()){
              ?>

            <option><?php echo $fetch['segment']?></option>

            <?php   }?>

    </select>
  </td>  </tr>

                             <?php       }



        ?>




        </tbody>
    </table>
             <form action="activate.php" method="post">
             <button class="btn btn-danger" name="save">Save</button>
```

i have inner join the three tables like this in class.php:

```
           public function selectFrom(){
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("select * from countrysegments 
   inner join country on countrysegments.country_id  = country.id
   inner join segments on countrysegments.segment_id = segments.id") or die($this->conn->error);
        if($stmt->execute()){
            $result = $stmt->get_result();
            return $result;
        }
    }
```

the question is that i have to insert into countrysegment table what everycountry have choose as segment

just i need help of the query and how might it done thank u

Comment: can u format the code

Comment: Can you tell whats needs to be inserted in countrysegments table.
or show the desired result of table.

Comment: every country must have one segment so i have to insert the id of the country and the id of the segment inside table countrysegments@Mack4Hack

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have posted values properly, try this following code

```
$country_id = $_REQUEST['country_id'];
$segment_id = $_REQUEST['segment_id'];

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO countrysegments (country_id, segment_id) VALUES (?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ii", $country_id, $segment_id);

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: i need for every country to choose one segment so i have myltiple countries and multiple segments, so i need to do a for loop but i dont know how to do that using arrays

Comment: you mean the posted array will be like this

array('country1'=>array('segemtn1','segment2'),'country2'=>array('segement1','segment2','segment3'))